# Firebase storage rule for authenticated user not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When I open my Firebase Storage bucket and go to files I have the following folder structure:

```
/<environment>/reports/<userId>/
```

I want that only the authenticated `userId` is allowed to read, write the reports in that user folder.

I tried the following, but it gives me the message that access is denied. What am I doing wrong? I copied almost one-to-one the example from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start?authuser=0#sample-rules).

```
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "<ENVIRONMENT>/reports/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /production/reports/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rules simulator in the [Firebase Storage Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage/rules) to test your rules. I've tested yours and they seem to be working OK:

[image: storage rules]

You'll need to remember to specify a final node name such as `/production/reports/{userId}/test` in order for the rule to work, as it will match the storage bucket filename rather than the parent directory due to `/{allPaths=**}`.

Comment: I see you tried with authenticated with anonymous. I have an user authenticated by email with a specific id. Have you tried creating a folder with a random userId?

Comment: It should work with any authentication method - I tested with the "password" method too and the simulator allowed write access, unless the `{userId}` and Firebase UID didn't match.

Comment: It seems indeed that in the simulator I had to access a path `/production/reports/user1/PATHNAME` instead of the root directory `/production/reports/user1` which I tried